# How can i use recaptcha v3 in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, recaptcha-v3

I know there are some ng captcha libraries out there. I didn't wanted just for one method call to install npm dependency. In the pure java script implementation for example onSubmit method call, when we submit the form we call this method from the google recaptcha api

```
 recaptcha.execute(secret_key, {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       c.log('token', token);
})
```

but i can't find a way, how can i tell angular and typescript that this recaptcha variable is from the google api and it will execute the `execute` method.

Now ofcourse i get the error

```
 recaptcha.execute is not a function
```

Have somoene found a way without library ?

Answer (score 2):

So this is the way

**app.component.ts**

```
declare var grecaptcha: any;
const siteKey = 'YOUR_SITE_KEY';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 
onSubmit() {
    grecaptcha.ready(() => {
      grecaptcha.execute(siteKey, { action: 'contactUs' }).then((token) => {
        console.log(token);
        let body = {
          firstName:this.firstName,
          captcha:token
        }
        this.recapService.checkRecaptcha(body).subscribe(res => {
          console.log('res', res);
        })
      });
    });
  }

}
```

**service**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecapService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  checkRecaptcha(body) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/subscribe', body);
  }
}
```